# oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"nodemon\": executable file not found in $PATH"

Tags: linux, docker

While running tasks on a ws ecs it is throwing error as

> CannotStartContainerError: API error (404): oci runtime error:
>   container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec:
>   \"nodemon\": executable file not found in $PATH

Here are the contents of my dockerfile

```
FROM node:8.4-wheezy
ENV VERSION 0.1
ENV DEV development
ENV DOC_ROOT /opt/app
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -yf nginx
RUN npm install --global nodemon
RUN npm install --global typescript rimraf
RUN mkdir -p ${DOC_ROOT}
COPY package.json ${DOC_ROOT}
RUN cd /opt/app && npm install
WORKDIR ${DOC_ROOT}
COPY . ${DOC_ROOT}

ENTRYPOINT ["nodemon", "server/server.js"]
```

Comment: Happens also on linux, so it is not amazon-ecs specific